# Не сохраняется изменение в <td> элементе при использовании innerHTML

Tags: javascript, selenium

Вопрос на грани Selenium и JavaScript.

В тесте пытаюсь изменить значение ячейки таблицы. Так как стандартный sendKeys с этим не умеет работать, решил использовать JavaScriptExecutor. С помощью метода executeScript вызываю выполнение innerHTML, всё ок, при запуске теста команда меняет значение в ячейке (визуально это вижу при воспроизведении), но как только фокус уходит с ячейки (попытка нажать кнопку сохранения или клик по другой ячейке) - возвращается старое значение в этой ячейке.

Вот так выглядит ячейка в Developer Tools:

```
<td атрибуты>::before "20"</td>
```

Команда, которой меняю значение.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 21", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(...));
```

Значение меняется с 20 на 21, но потом опять становится 20.

Comment: Возможно стоит слушатель, который отлавливает событие и проверяет данные(перезаписывает), что бы нельзя было, как раз через devTools изменить значения и отправить неверные данные

Comment: Ну, меняю я не через devTools, его я только для просмотра кода страницы использую. Тут я просто указал, как ячейка выглядит до выполнения команды.

Comment: Да не суть... Данные меняются на странице. При нажатии кнопки, срабатывает какой нибудь скрипт, которые проверяет корректность данных или просто заново их расставляет

Comment: Да, там есть проверка валидности введенных данных в таблице. Видимо, этого скрипта работа. Тогда вопрос, а как это обойти можно? Или не innerHTML использовать, а как-то по другому данные в ячейку прокинуть?

Comment: Не знаю... Возможно можно как то этот скрипт удалить или чем то заменить, может можно как то атрибут в ячейке поменять, что бы скрипт не нашел(не известно, как он работает и что вообще делает).  Однако, если вмешаться в код и что то там переделать, можно убить функциональность и все сломается, тогда, собственно, и тестировать уже не за чем )

Comment: Ясно, пойду разрабов пинать по поводу работы скрипта. ) Спасибо!